# Is there a hook to alter webform confirmation message?

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

In Drupal 7 using webforms, is there a `hook` that can alter the outgoing confirmation message shown to someone who has just submitted a form?

[image]

My thoughts are to put a text placeholder inside this textarea and do a `str_replace` to update the output based the submission itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution for using submissions value in Submission confirmation message is using [Webform Tokens module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_tokens).

And another solution as you asked is using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) add your custom submit handler ( make sure yours getting run before webform's default) change the submitted string with what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Like the @zhilevan told you can use hook_form_alter for placeholder and for `str_replace` you can implement `hook_template_preprocess`.

Here is an example.

```
function my_module_preprocess_webform_confirmation(&$vars) {

    $confirmation = check_markup($vars['node']->webform['confirmation'], $vars['node']->webform['confirmation_format'], '', TRUE);
    module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions');
    $submission = webform_get_submission($vars['node']->nid, $vars['sid']);
    $confirmation = _webform_filter_values($confirmation, $vars['node'], $submission, NULL, FALSE, TRUE);

   // Strip out empty tags added by WYSIWYG editors if needed.
   $vars['confirmation_message'] = strlen(trim(strip_tags($confirmation))) ? $confirmation : '';

}
```

Source [Webform Token support on confirmation message](https://www.drupal.org/node/828566).

you can also take a look on tpl file option.
Here [webform-confirmation.tpl.php](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!templates!webform-confirmation.tpl.php/7)