# Changing the HTML of Webform Confirmation popup

Tags: webforms

I want to override the default HTML that loads on a webform confirmation popup but couldn't find a hook for that.

Can anyone help ?

Thanks,
Yaron

Comment: Maybe there is an answer here, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/216122/is-there-a-hook-to-alter-webform-confirmation-message

Comment: No, unfortunately I need to change the entire structure, not only the inner content. I need a hook that allows me full control of the HTML popup.

Comment: Are you using D8 or D7?

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274747/programmatically-change-webform-confirmation-page

Comment: I'm using D8. Still it isn't precisely what I want. I don't want to load/redirect another page. I want to load my own popup...